# mapDispatchToProps shorthand causing flow type checking error

Tags: javascript, redux, flowtype

I'd like to use the shorthand notation for `mapDispatchToProps`, but when I replace the old fashioned `bindActionCreators` strategy

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<any>): PropsFromDispatch {
  return {
    fetchStuff: () => dispatch(fetchStuffAction()),
  };
}
....
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

with the `mapDispatchToProps` shorthand object syntax

```
const actions = {
  fetchStuff: fetchStuffAction,
};
...
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(MyComponent);
```

I get the following complaint from the flow type checker...

```
Cannot call connect because:
 • Either a callable signature is missing in object literal [1] but exists in MapDispatchToProps [2].
 • Or a callable signature is missing in object literal [1] but exists in MapDispatchToProps [3].
```

any ideas?

`react-redux v5.0.7`
`flow-bin v0.69.0`

Comment: please post some relevant code

Comment: That awkward moment when you look up a [Github issue and OP has already looked there and commented](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/issues/746).

Do you mind also posting what libdef version you have? I assume `react-redux_v5.x.x.js` but want to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<*>) => ({
  fetchStuff: () => dispatch(fetchStuffAction())
})
```

You need to do smth like this. Dispatch type is not any..